# Redirect traffic between LAN and OPT1

Tags: networking, firewall, port-forwarding, nat

In Pfsense, I have two network cards, one connected to a network 192.168.56.2 which is the LAN network and the other one is connected to the network 192.168.58.2 which is the OPT1 network; these are the two IP addresses that each of the cards has in the Pfsense service. I have a server on the network 192.168.56.5 that has a web on port 8080; then I have a client on the network 192.168.58.16; how can I use port forwarding so that when I make a request to the address 192.168.58.2:8080 it redirects me to the address 192.168.56.5:8080?

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu?